# How to recover deleted .git/modules folder

Tags: git, git-submodules

In my project .git/modules folder got deleted. Now I am able to reset the parent branch to other versions but submodule update is not working.

Error I am receiving:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/abc.
Unable to find current revision in submodule path 'abc'
```

How can I recover the deleted folder and bring back the submodule in line with parent branch.

Repo structure is like this:

```
parent_folder---|---abc
                |---def
```

**abc and def are submodules.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to init & update the submodules again,

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

It should download and update the current submodules code.

If its still doesnt work try to remove the submodule and add it again with the

```
git submodule add <params>
```

And if this doesn't resolve it , add the submodule with the `--force` flag

> If `--force` is specified, the submodule will be checked out (using git checkout --force if appropriate), even if the commit specified in the index of the containing repository already matches the commit checked out in the submodule.

Comment: First method didnt work. Also while adding the submodule it gave an error saying index already exists. So I deleted everything and did submodule init and submodule update. Code came but I lost previous branches in submodule. Is there any way to recover that?

Comment: Have you deleted the folder? if you deleted the content you will have to pull them from the server

Comment: Yes I deleted the abc and def folder as mentioned in the example. I had few working branches in abc folder but I didn't do git push.

Answer (score 0):

I am extending on CodeWizard's answer.

If you get

> **fatal**: No URL for Submodul-Path 'app/design/Foo/Bar' in .gitmodules
>   found

Then execute `git rm app/design/Foo/Bar` or `git rm --cached app/design/Foo/Bar` and try again.

If you then get

> **fatal**: Could not find repository-handle for Submodul 'app/code/Foo/Bar'.

Then it is probably because you deleted the folder in .git/modules.

The submodules **.git** file in app/code/Foo/bar is just a "fake" file which references the real git repo in **.git/modules**. It is not a real repository. If you open it, you see:

```
gitdir: ../../../../.git/modules/app/code/Foo/Bar
```

So just **delete** the folder "*app/code/Foo/Bar*" and try again.